# I want to encrypt content on USB or SD Card

Tags: encryption, storage

I want to encrypt the content on a USB or SD card that can only be decrypted by an app installed on any device or TV. When the USB is not connected to that particular app, it should not be accessible. Is it possible? Which tool or software should I use?

Comment: A simple solution would be to just put a password-protected (=encrypted) zip archive on the device.

Comment: @Philipp not really, since ALOT of apps/devices/tv's etc cannot natively understand .zip files, let alone encrypted .zip files.

Comment: @Lighty You will have that problem with *any* encryption method. There is no standard for USB or SD encryption which is universally supported out-of-the-box by devices from more than one manufacturer.

Comment: @Philipp thats why the awnser for this question is simply no, there is no way, because alot of devices dont support the same applications/ways of encrypting storage devices and such

Comment: If any TV can decrypt it, then anyone could decrypt the content just by plugging it into a TV. I'm not sure how you expect to have any protection from your imagined scheme.

Answer (score 2):

You are out of luck.

There is no universally adopted standard for encryption of USB or SD cards. That means no matter which method you choose, you will have to install some software on the reading device to decrypt your data.

Unfortunately most embedded devices like TVs don't allow to install any additional software on them. When your smart TV doesn't support some encryption scheme out-of-the-box (likely it doesn't) you will have a hard time to install one.